# Custom validation :on => :create not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom validation method that I only want executed on create:

```
validate :post_count, :on => :create

def post_count
  # validate stuff
end
```

However, it's getting fired on update (in addition to on create).

Does the `:on => :create` option not work with custom validation methods?

Comment: Could you update the title and tag to clarify about what Rails version you are using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no `:on` option. Use

```
validate_on_create :post_count
```

instead. And there's `validate_on_update` also. You can read about this methods [**here**](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html).

Comment: That's odd, i was sure :on existed... hmmm

Comment: There is, validate_on_create is actually deprecated, DEPRECATION WARNING validate_on_create is deprecated. Please use validate(args, :on => :create)

Answer (score 7):

This may be a Rails 2.x vs. Rails 3 issue but according to the [Rails Guides on Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on) the `:on` option is definitely valid (though I am fighting with why it's not firing for me in a similar way).